# Enabling Strict Mode in Existing Angular Project

Tags: angular, typescript

I have taken over an older Angular project and working on upgrading, etc. One of the items I want to implement is strict mode. In looking at the docs, enabling strict mode upon project creation is shown, but I cannot find documentation on how to implement it in an existing project. I have found some posts that mention some various option properties that will be set, but I do not want to miss anything. Can someone point me in the right direction to get strict mode set up properly for an existing Angular (11) project? I found information for v.10. I was wondering if there were v.11 changes?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/typescript-configuration

Comment: try this: https://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2020/09/angular-10strict-mode.html